# Using coalesce on an index column

Tags: mysql, performance, index

Does doing a COALESCE on an indexed columns in a WHERE clause e.g. `WHERE COALESCE(table1.indexed_column, '9999-01-01') > table2.other_date_column` affect indexing in a bad way?
I think that it should but in this case how should I convert my where clause?

Comment: You think it should do what? It seems like some verb was removed from the sentence.

Comment: COALESCE is a function and not SARGable.  Ergo, it won't use an index directly.

Comment: Are the 2 columns in the same table or in 2 different ones?

Comment: @ypercube:different tables.I will update OP.Good point

Answer (score 4):

If you afraid that the condition will keep the optimizer from using an index on the columns, you are right, the use of functions in most DBMS has this effect. There are some exceptions to the rule but not in MySQL.

If you want indexes to be considered (and possibly used), you have to conevrt the condition to one without functions applied to columns.

Your condition, (if `table2.other_date_column` is not nullable), is equivalent to:

```
 (  table1.indexed_column > table2.other_date_column 
 OR table1.indexed_column IS NULL )
```

Comment: Updated OP.The columns are from different tables

Comment: 1)How is the comparison with NULL going to work in your condition? 2) Hm... the column is not defined as not nullable but currently there are no NULL values in the table

Comment: `table1.indexed_column > table.other_date_column` this returns NULL if `table1.indexed_column` is null. So what is the idea here?

Comment: The first line is used if the `table1.indexed_column` is not null. If it is null, the 2nd line become true and the condition becomes `NULL OR TRUE` which is `TRUE`.

Comment: If I used an `IF()` for this would that also hinder the indexing?

Comment: Yes, `IF()` is a function, too.

Comment: `table2.other_data_column` is not defined as NOT NULL. What happens if `table2.other_data_column` is NULL

Comment: What do you want to happen is the right question. And what if both columns have NULL.